# How to open new controller for the UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have follow https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/autolayout-programmatically-spotify-clone-in-swift/ to create a uicollectionview but the different is I use UIView to implement. However I don't know how to click to each cell of the Sub-UICollectionCell  and open a new UIController. Below is my code.

```
Class HomeView : UIView,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate   ,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{
    lazy var collectionView : UICollectionView = {
      let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
      let cv = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
      cv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      cv.delegate = self
      cv.dataSource = self
      cv.register(HomeCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "cellId")
      cv.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexString: "#F7F7F7")
      return cv
    }()
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      addSubview(collectionView)

    }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
      return sections.count
   }


   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)  -> UICollectionViewCell {
      let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! HomeCollectionViewCell
      cell.section = sections[indexPath.item]

      return cell
    }
```

}

where I have HomeCollectionCell as

```
class HomeCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell , UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UICollectionViewDataSource{
   override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      addSubview(titleLabel)
      collectionView.dataSource = self
      collectionView.delegate = self
      collectionView.register(SubHomeViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
      setupSubCells()
    }

  fileprivate  func setupSubCells(){
       // add collectionView to the view
       addSubview(collectionView)

       collectionView.dataSource = self
       collectionView.delegate = self

   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return  self.subCategorys.count
   }
   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
       let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! SubHomeViewCell
       cell.subCategory = subCategorys[indexPath.item]
       return cell
   }

   func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

       let width = frame.height
       let height = frame.height

       return CGSize(width: width, height: height)

  }
```

}

For my SubHomeView I just add the addSubview of image and title 
I need to click each cell to open a controller page to show each menu detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass in a `weak var` reference to your controller in `HomeView`.Then, use `didSelectItemAt` method of `UICollectionView` inside your `HomeView`, here is an example:

```swift
weak var homeViewController: HomeViewController?

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let newViewController = UIViewController()
    newViewController.view.backgroundColor = .purple
    homeViewController?.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: This work for the UICollectionView in HomeView, But I want to open the controller when I click on the sub-UICollectionView (UICollectionView in HomeCollectionViewCell). Do you have any idea to implement it?

Comment: Pass the homeVC to your `sub-UICollectionView` as weak var.